# Query customer portal logged in user related Contact and Account?

Tags: trigger, soql, community, query, user

If a user login to the customer portal,if he tries to raise a case, in case edit page the account and contact lookup fields are there how we get account and contact values automatically by user clicking the new case button?

Comment: Are these the account and contact details that relate to that customer user?

Comment: yes From Salesforce users list take one Customer portal user in users detail page we find related contact by clicking that contact it will display contacts details page in that page we find account lookup field.finally we want that both account and contact values by that user logins to the customer portal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the related `Contact` using `ContactId`, and query related `Contact` details using `Contact.SomeField__c`. Similarly, you can query the related Account using `Contact.AccountId`.

```
SELECT
    Username,
    ContactId, Contact.Name,
    Contact.AccountId, Contact.Account.Name
FROM User
WHERE Id = 'community_user_id'
```

If the user in question is the running user, simply change the `WHERE` clause to:

```
WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()
```

Comment: Could you also use ```id = UserInfo.getUserId()``` instead of ```id= 'community user'```?

Comment: Absolutely for code run as that user.

Comment: here id ='community_user_id' place can i pass like this id='High volume customer portal user' (or) user id value i will pass,if i pass the user id it will be static i want dynamic

Comment: @chandra are you trying to get this data when the community user is the running user?

Comment: @chandra you do realize that ``community_user_id`` is just a place holder in the query. You need to pass the actual user id.